# Need to integrate crashlytics in SDK made by us. how can i?

Tags: android, sdk, crash, crashlytics-android

I want to identify the crashes in my SDK when some other apps integrate my SDK in their app.. during the use of my SDK in other apps, if crashes happen anywhere in my SDK code, then I want to identify that.

What are the ways to implement this type of integration in SDK?

Comment: Have you discussed this plan with your attorney?

Comment: Not yet...  I am not sure, but do we need to discuss that with the attorney.? @CommonsWare

Comment: I certainly recommend it. At minimum, the terms of service and license that cover your SDK need to accommodate your desire to spy on crashes. At worst, you wind up in prison, because you spied on crashes for apps in certain industries with serious privacy laws (health care, financial services, etc.). Any sort of library telemetry -- crashes, analytics, etc. -- needs to be vetted by qualified legal counsel, to ensure that when Random Developer X starts using your library, you do not get in trouble.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for sharing this useful information. let me discuss with my seniors for this point.

Answer (score 2):

To integrate Crashlytics you need to configure Firebase for your app package.

Since the app package is not **your** app package, but the package of the consumer of your SDK, it's impossible.

I believe there is an alternative way of doing so (check out `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)` and wrap the existing one), but I recommend, as been said in the comments, to check how you can **legally** do it.

I'm guessing (pure guess so don't take my word for it) that you need a written consent from you SDK customer and also runtime consent from the end user.

## That being said - I strongly recommend not to do it.

**Alternative legal** way to do it:

- Create an exception class, dedicated for your SDK. For example, if your SDK is called "My SDK" so create `MySdkException`.
- Only throw `MySdkException` from within your SDK.
- Embed libraries within your SDK and wrap their exceptions with `MySdkException`.
- Don't obfuscate `MySdkException`.
- The most important - **kindly ask your SDK consumer** to report any crashes caused by `MySdkException`.
- Verify that your SDK customer asks the end-user to agree Crash report.